# Verification of regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, econometrics, poisson-regression

I am performing a regression analysis on some macro economic factors with default rate. When I predict the default rate from regression equation I am getting a negative default rate. As you know default rate can not be negative. Can anyone please suggest me what is the best way to deal with this (negative default rate)? 
Is there any other method which I should use?

Comment: Many non-economists here might well be like me and not even have a clear idea of what default rate means. But why be surprised? A regression surface that is tilted must predict negative responses somewhere; the only question is whether the negative predictions occur within the range of the data. But, to the point, non-negative responses call for a logarithmic link function or Poisson regression in its widest sense. See e.g. http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend

Comment: Use a regression model for positive data?